# SQLAlchemy: Creating vs. Reusing a Session

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Just a quick question: SQLAlchemy [talks about](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/session.html#session-frequently-asked-questions) calling `sessionmaker()` once but calling the resulting `Session()` class each time you need to talk to your DB. For me that means the second I would do my first `session.add(x)` or something similar, I would first do

```
from project import Session
session = Session()
```

What I did until now was to make the call `session = Session()` in my model *once* and then always import the same session anywhere in my application. Since this is a web-applications this would *usually* mean the same (as one view is executed).

But where is the difference? What is the disadvantage of using one session all the time against using it for my database stuff until my function is done and then creating a new one the next time I want to talk to my DB?

I get that if I use multiple threads, each one should get their own session. But using `scoped_session()`, I already make sure that problem doesn't exist, do I?

Please clarify if any of my assumptions are wrong.

Answer (score 370, accepted):

`sessionmaker()` is a factory, it's there to encourage placing configuration options for creating new `Session` objects in just one place.   It is optional, in that you could just as easily call `Session(bind=engine, expire_on_commit=False)` anytime you needed a new `Session`, except that its verbose and redundant, and I wanted to stop the proliferation of small-scale "helpers" that each approached the issue of this redundancy in some new and more confusing way.

So `sessionmaker()` is just a tool to help you create `Session` objects when you need them.

Next part.   I think the question is, what's the difference between making a new `Session()` at various points versus just using one all the way through.  The answer, not very much.   `Session` is a container for all the objects you put into it, and then it also keeps track of an open transaction.  At the moment you call `rollback()` or `commit()`, the transaction is over, and the `Session` has no connection to the database until it is called upon to emit SQL again.   The links it holds to your mapped objects are weak referencing, provided the objects are clean of pending changes, so even in that regard the `Session` will empty itself out back to a brand new state when your application loses all references to mapped objects.  If you leave it with its default `"expire_on_commit"` setting, then all the objects are expired after a commit.  If that `Session` hangs around for five or twenty minutes, and all kinds of things have changed in the database the next time you use it, it will load all brand new state the next time you access those objects even though they've been sitting in memory for twenty minutes.

In web applications, we usually say, hey why don't you make a brand new `Session` on each request, rather than using the same one over and over again.  This practice ensures that the new request begins "clean".  If some objects from the previous request haven't been garbage collected yet, and if maybe you've turned off `"expire_on_commit"`, maybe some state from the previous request is still hanging around, and that state might even be pretty old.   If you're careful to leave `expire_on_commit` turned on and to definitely call `commit()` or `rollback()` at request end, then it's fine, but if you start with a brand new `Session`, then there's not even any question that you're starting clean.   So the idea to start each request with a new `Session` is really just the simplest way to make sure you're starting fresh, and to make the usage of `expire_on_commit` pretty much optional, as this flag can incur a lot of extra SQL for an operation that calls `commit()` in the middle of a series of operations.   Not sure if this answers your question.

The next round is what you mention about threading.   If your app is multithreaded, we recommend making sure the `Session` in use is local to...something.   `scoped_session()` by default makes it local to the current thread.  In a web app, local to the request is in fact even better.   Flask-SQLAlchemy actually sends a custom "scope function" to `scoped_session()` so that you get a request-scoped session.  The average Pyramid application sticks the Session into the "request" registry.   When using schemes like these, the "create new Session on request start" idea continues to look like the most straightforward way to keep things straight.

Comment: Wow, this answers all my questions on the SQLAlchemy part and even adds some info about Flask and Pyramid! Added bonus: developers answer ;) I wish I could vote more than once. Thank you very much!

Comment: One clarification, if possible: you say expire_on_commit "can incur a lot of extra SQL"... can you give more details? I thought expire_on_commit only concerned what happens in RAM, not what happens in the database.

Comment: expire_on_commit can result in more SQL if you re-use the same Session again, and some objects are still hanging around in that Session, when you access them you'll get a single-row SELECT for each one of them as they each individually refresh their state in terms of the new transaction.

Comment: Hi, @zzzeek. Thanks for excellent answer. I'm very new in python and several things I wanna clarify: 1) Do I understand correct when I create new 
"session" by calling Session() method it will create SQL Transaction, then transaction will be opened until I commit/rollback session? 2) Does session() use some kind of connection pool or makes new connection to sql each time?

Comment: For me (using Snowflake), there is a noticeable difference in performance of about 1.2s when creating a new Session each time versus reusing the same one.

Comment: Great answer!! This still leaves me super confused about how sessions map to db connections and how sql alchemy connection pooling works, can you elaborate?

Comment: This answer should be included in the docs!

Answer (score 40):

In addition to the excellent zzzeek's answer, here's a simple recipe to quickly create throwaway, self-enclosed sessions:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

@contextmanager
def db_session(db_url):
    """ Creates a context with an open SQLAlchemy session.
    """
    engine = create_engine(db_url, convert_unicode=True)
    connection = engine.connect()
    db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=True, bind=engine))
    yield db_session
    db_session.close()
    connection.close()
```

Usage:

```
from mymodels import Foo

with db_session("sqlite://") as db:
    foos = db.query(Foo).all()
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you create not just a new session, but a fresh connection too?

Comment: Not really - this is a quick example to show the mechanism, although it does make sense to create everything fresh in testing, where I use this approach the most. It should be easy to expand this function with the connection as an optional argument.

Comment: I had to write `db_session.commit()` inside the `db_session` to make it work (updates ofcourse)

Comment: I believe that can be avoided by setting `autocommit=True` in the call to `sessionmaker`.