# Check values for session_options programmatically in SQLAlchemy

Tags: session, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

How can I check in flask shell the `session_options` like "expire_on_commit".

Further how can I set these options in flask-sqlalchemy.
Referring to insightful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12223711/631775

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the source code for `Session` (https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py), the options which are passed to `Session` or `sessionmaker`, such as `expire_on_commit`, are  just stored as attributes on the `Session` object.

I'm not overly familiar with flask shell but if you have access to the session object through the test request context at that point, or provision it some other way, you can inspect the session object directly for this info.

From http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/sqlalchemy/, Flask-SQLAlchemy uses a scoped session which allows each thread to have a unique session. You pass it a sessionmaker which you can configure to set the default configuration for all Sessions in your application.