# pandas read_sql_query using scoped session

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to call pandas.read_sql_query using the alchemy session ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/33648514)? 
example:

```
with db_session(connection) as db:
    df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, db, index_col=None, coerce_float...)
```

So far I have received the following error:

> AttributeError: 'scoped_session' object has no attribute 'cursor'

However I beleive it is good practice to use sessions instead of just reading using a sql alchemy connection/engine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the SQLAlchemy session by passing `session.connection()`.

```py
with db_session(connection_url) as session:
    # session.execute('INSERT INTO ...')
    df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, session.connection())
```

A possible use case, as shown in the commented code above, is to read uncommitted changes.

## Reusing connections

A more reasonable way to use SQLAlchemy sessions is reusing connections from `engine` pool.

Define once:

```py
engine = create_engine(connection_url)
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
```

Call any number of times:

```py
with Session() as session:
    # session.execute('INSERT INTO ...')
    df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, session.connection())
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to call `pandas.read_sql_query` using the SQLAlchemy session.

In your example, `db` is the session (`sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session`). So just use `db.bind`:

```
dp = pd.read_sql_query(sql_query, db.bind, ...)
```

But it will be the same as passing the engine used to create the session.